# Next js 13 slow compiling problem with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I want to use Material UI with next js 13 (App router)  but it's taking too much compiling time during development.  How to fix it? Is there any configuration to decrease the compiling time during development?

I want to use Material UI with next js 13 app router but getting slow compiling

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37614#discussioncomment-3036716) answer your question?

Comment: I found a possible solution https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37614#discussioncomment-3036716

Comment: That is exactly what I have commented

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, I did some digging, and these are ideas that I've tried that optimize development building (not production building) with MUI and Next.js:

**Option 1: Switch to Turbopack during npm run dev (warning: in beta)**
I measured a 10-60% improvement in speed. I don't know why it's so variable.

1. Below are versions of MUI and Next.js that I'm using in package.json. When upgrading from MUI from 5.14 to 5.15 and Next.js from 13.5 to 14.0, I changed the boilerplate a bit. See this [example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.15.12/examples/material-ui-nextjs-ts/src/app/layout.tsx) and mui [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/).

```
    "@emotion/cache": "~11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "~11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "~11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "~5.15.12",
    "@mui/material": "~5.15.12",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "~5.15.11",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "~6.19.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "~6.19.0",
    "next": "~14.0.4",
```

2. Next, add the `--turbo` flag in the package.json. For more information please see Next.js [turbopack](https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/turbopack) documentation.

**Option 2: Lazy Load & Exclude selective libraries from initial webpack**
I have a feeling there is a better way to do this, but this does work. I measured a ~60% improvement in speed, but I also didn't take a lot of measurements so this might also be highly variable.

1. I used [BundleAnalyzer](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/bundle-analyzer) to analyze which packages were the largest.
2. I found that @mui/x-data-grid and xlsx were a large packages and only some of my page.tsx files required it. The rest of the example uses xlsx, but I'm sure you could apply it to @mui/x-data-grid.
3. Run `npm uninstall xlsx` in the root directory of your project.
4. In my `src/libs` folder I created a `xlsx` folder with an `xlsx.js` file with the following code:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
module.exports = require('./node_modules/xlsx');
```

5. In the `xlsx` folder, I created the following `packages.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "xlsx",
  "main": "xlsx.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "xlsx": "git+https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs.git#v0.19.3"
  }
}
```

6. Run `npm install --save-dev` after you've cd'd in to the xlsx folder.
7. In the button event where the user needs to parse the uploaded xlsx file, I lazy load the package. Please see Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-external-libraries) for a deeper explanation.

```
    const xlsx = (await import('@/libs/xlsx')).default;
    const { read, utils: xlsxUtils } = xlsx;
    const { files } = event.target;
```

I ended up using and merging Option 1 into my main branch. I also have a feeling you could combine the two options for even more speed.